# ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python-nonfree

Tags: python, opencv, sift, opencv-contrib

I am trying to install opencv nonfree on windows version to run the sift.

```
PS F:\DKE\CV\cvfinal> pip install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python-nonfree (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python-nonfree`
```

can someone help me to install this .i don't want to use cmake to created the package because its giving me some other errors.I am using the python 3.8.2 64 bit version ith pip

```
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

can some please help me

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use PYTHON on my computer but you can see the video.

C++: I have solved it by installing Cmake, and later using opencv_master and opencv_contrib_master. You have to install Cmake and add it to the Path directories on windows. Later you will have to add opencv_master to Cmake an configure it, check none error is matched, later you have to add opencv_contrib_master/include to EXTRA_MODULES, you have to choice NONFREE and WORLD option, configure and generate. Thats the most important, you can use the next video. It work for me, just remember to use the instrucctions above.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fqpYLM6SCw&t=312s

Comment: but I don't want to use cmake, because I have some other error. Is there no any other way to install it?

Comment: I tried to install contrib libraries from CMD, it did not work. Yes, it was installed but when I tried to use SIFT and SURF, compiler advised me that it was not implemented.